# PHP 5.2 Notice: Use of undefined constant __DIR__ - assumed '__DIR__

Tags: php

In php 5.3 or less it'll provide an error like the following:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant __DIR__ - assumed '__DIR__
```

It's because i'm using the magic constant `__DIR__`. Is there an alternative to using `__DIR__` in 5.3 or less??

Here's the code that's causing it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Load template files
 *
 * $files   Contains alphabetized list of files that will be required
 */
$files = array(
  'elements.inc',
  'form.inc',
  'menu.inc',
  'theme.inc',
);

function _zurb_foundation_load($files) {
  $tp = drupal_get_path('theme', 'zurb_foundation');
  $file = '';

  // Workaround for magic constant; for now because of php 5.2 issue
  // http://drupal.org/node/1899620#comment-6988766
  if( !defined( __DIR__ ) )define( __DIR__, dirname(__FILE__) );

  // Check file path and '.inc' extension
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $file_path = __DIR__ .'/inc/' . $file;
    if ( strpos($file,'.inc') > 0 && file_exists($file_path)) {
      require_once($file_path);
    }
  }
}

_zurb_foundation_load($files);
```

Comment: Better idea: Update. PHP5.2 is not maintained anymore. And sooner or later and update is a good idea anyway ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch true i was thinking that from the get go; but it's like an internet explorer 6 problem. People don't want to give it up

Comment: IE6 is unsupported by MS itself, you know? ;) PHP5.2 must be treated as unsecure. On the other side 5.4 is out for a while now and even 5.5 will come somewhere between april and june. In my opinion it is not useful to give "this people" reasons to stick on 5.2

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? I only have to write a workaround because it's for an open source project, Drupal 7, which supports php 5.2.

Comment: @Leigh Ah alright. Great. Could you please name the man page for this issue?

Comment: @chrisjlee sure [http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Glad i'm not the only one. Seems like there are 10,000 others with the same problem.

Comment: Thought this was actually a useful question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the old trick:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

But if possible, update to a newer version of PHP.

Comment: That's acceptable to use even after 5.3 ?

Comment: @chrisjlee Yes it produces the same result

Comment: "acceptable" maybe, but you should prefer `__DIR__` for readability.

Comment: @KingCrunch On PHP 5.3+ I will use `__DIR__` without hesitations. But for compatibility with earlier versions `dirname(__FILE__)` is not *that* ugly and widely used. And in my opinion `dirname(__FILE__)` is far more readable than `if( !defined( __DIR__ ) )define( __DIR__, dirname(__FILE__) );`

Comment: @MathieuImbert As mentioned in my comment to the question itself: 5.2 is unmaintained. Or can you buy modern games compatible to windows 98 nowadays? // I would keep this whole `define()`-crap away: If `__DIR__` doesn't exists, the runtime is incompatible. Thats it.

Comment: @KingCrunch I agree, best thing to do is to upgrade. But to follow up with your example, I still keep an old Windows 98 for old games whose code wasn't updated for earlier operating systems.

Comment: @MathieuImbert For _old_ games, ok. ;) But I guess you would never blame EA (or whomever), because their actual games require Vista, or 8 (or maybe XP). The point is, that I see it kind of critical to support update-lazy people in their attitude. It gives them reason to stick on 5.2 (unsecure and so on), which gives other developers even more reason to develop for 5.2 and so on. There must be an end!!1111 :D ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch Absolutely. I added a mention about upgrading in my answer. I completely understand your point and I am not advising to stick with an old version. But I still have a few insane scripts or tools (nothing in production) that are not compatible with PHP 5.3 or 5.4. I was a big fan of `ereg` functions and I would not consider updating them since I will no longer use these scripts in a near future. In this specific cases I would use compatibility tricks.

Comment: @MathieuImbert As my final note: PHP5.2 should be able to seamlessly run on 5.3, or it is written "not so good" in the first place :D. Most code only needs some minor adjustments to run. And even if not, it is not that hard to compile a PHP yourself, at least on linux. In fact (as long as all packages are installed) it's only a `./configure <options>;make; make install;`. // And regarding `ereg`: The main difference is, that `preg_*()` requires delimiters :D No real downside.

Comment: Worked for me on PHP 5.2